# How to get a DTD's public and system IDs with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dtd, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to retrieve the public and system IDs for a DTD in an XML document via `NSXMLParser`. While `NSXMLParser` in principal offers `publicID` and `systemID` selectors they don't seem to work for me. The doctype tag looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE Article PUBLIC "-//SoftQuad Software//DTD Journalist v2.0 20000501//EN" "file:///C:/Program%20Files/Corel/XMetaL%204/Author/Rules/journalist.dtd">
```

Here's my code (the file was opened via `NSFileHandle`'s `readDataToEndOfFile`:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
BOOL parseSuccessful = [parser parse];
```

In the delegate's `parserDidStartDocument:` I try to access the IDs:

```
NSLog(@"%@ : %@", [parser publicID], [parser systemID]);
```

But I only see

```
(null) : (null)
```

From the documentation:

> You may invoke this method once a parsing operation has begun or after an error occurs.

So I'd think this should work already in `parserDidStartDocument:` but I tried to call these selectors in different delegate methods (like `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` but without success.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might try out another parser.

http://www.robbiehanson.com/expat.html provides a drop-in replacement for NSXMLParser based on expat.

You might also find this article interesting, comparing the performance of various XML parsers on the iPhone.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project